# JSObject dependent applet - Using applet viewer at development time

Tags: java, swing, applet, development-environment, jsobject

I am using Java Plug-in and JSObject for DOM/JS <-> Applet communication.

I am using Eclipse IDE and at development time, I like the simplicity of Run/Debug As->Applet to launch and quickly see my layout/changes reflected in the running applet.
But I need to use JSObject to get some data that will come from the parent DOM/JS.

What is the best way to use Applet Viewer in this case?

One thing I can think of is to fake the DOM/JS calls in a delegate/wrapper and pass back mock objects if running under applet viewer (Basically if cannot obtain JSObject.getWindow)

I dont do a lot of applet development so was wondering if there is a better way to handle this? (Seems like this should be a common scenario)

Comment: *"(Seems like this should be a common scenario)"*  There's no accounting for the way things seem.  About 1 in 20 of current Java jobs relate to client-side technologies (as opposed to server-side).  Applets are a minor part of the rich client spectrum.  Applets that use the `JSObject` would be around 1 out of fifty instances.

Comment: :) @ Andrew I meant common scenario among those 5-10 people in the world who might be following the jsobject/applet SO tags that I tagged the question with.

Comment: Like the joke, but honestly, shoehorning the JS object into a tool that does not even support JavaScript (or even, for that matter, the applet based `showDocument()`)?  Good luck with that.  If I were (crazy enough to be) attempting this, I'd probably start with the code of [Appleteer](http://pscode.org/appleteer/) then look to the 'Voodoo API' for the rest.